# Changing ImageButton's background programmatically

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I am using custom action bar in an Android app, which has custom `ImageButton`s on the right, with their onClick behaviour added programatically (see code snippet below).

**XML source of the button**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_right_menu"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_refresh" />
```

**OnClickListener source**

```
mRefreshButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            doSomething();
    }
});
```

I would like to change the background color of my `ImageButton` programatically (without having to use additional graphics), so that the background would change when the user clicks on the button (**after the click the background should go back to normal, i.e. transparent**). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector for your `ImageButton` and set background from xml.

*If you want to use Drawable Images:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_bg" /> <!-- pressed -->
        <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/focused_bh" /> <!-- focused -->
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_bg" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

*If you want to use just color:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />    
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
     <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `invalidate()` method will force a redraw of any view:

Try using this:

```
mRefreshButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);
mRefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.replacementGraphic);
    mRefreshButton .setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
    mRefreshButton .invalidate();
    }
});
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

To change color you can use the following

```
Btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

To set back to transparent

```
Btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```